# Erasing pointers from vector while iterating another vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have tried many other similar questions but none of them helped me. My problem is as following:
I have 3 vectors of pointers to my struct: `vector<state*>`where `state` is my kind of struct. What I am trying to do is to remove states from `vectorCheck` if they are in either `vectorOpen` or `vectorClosed`. The point is, it sometimes works fine and sometimes not. According to CodeBlocks [image: debugger] this seems to be a problem but I have no idea to overcome this. I debugged my program step by step and at some point, state from `vectorCheck` is not being removed despite of the fact it is in `vectorClosed`.

Iterating is held by 2 for loops:

```
vector<state*> vectorOpen;
vector<state*>::iterator itOpen;
vector<state*> vectorClosed;
vector<state*>::iterator itClosed;
vector<state*> vectorCheck;
vector<state*>::iterator itCheck;

for(itCheck = vectorCheck.begin(); itCheck != vectorCheck.end(); itCheck++) {
        for(itOpen = vectorOpen.begin(); itOpen != vectorOpen.end(); itOpen++) {
            if ((*itCheck)->player->x == (*itOpen)->player->x &&
               (*itCheck)->player->y == (*itOpen)->player->y &&
               (*itCheck)->box[0].x == (*itOpen)->box[0].x &&
               (*itCheck)->box[0].y == (*itOpen)->box[0].y) {
                cout << "erasing as in open " << (*itCheck)->player->x << "   " << (*itCheck)->player->y << "   " << (*itCheck)->box[0].x << "   " << (*itCheck)->box[0].y << endl;
                vectorCheck.erase(itCheck);
            }
        }
    }

    for(itCheck = vectorCheck.begin(); itCheck != vectorCheck.end(); itCheck++) {
        for(itClosed = vectorClosed.begin(); itClosed != vectorClosed.end(); itClosed++) {
            if((*itCheck)->player->x == (*itClosed)->player->x &&
               (*itCheck)->player->y == (*itClosed)->player->y &&
               (*itCheck)->box[0].x == (*itClosed)->box[0].x &&
               (*itCheck)->box[0].y == (*itClosed)->box[0].y) {
                cout << "erasing as in closed " << (*itCheck)->player->x << "   " << (*itCheck)->player->y << "   " << (*itCheck)->box[0].x << "   " << (*itCheck)->box[0].y << endl;
                vectorCheck.erase(itCheck);
            }
        }
    }
```

Where `vectorCheck` is a maximum size of 3. To explain what I mean here is the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQJhi.jpg)
Where I am talking here about states in green rectangulars (3 1 2 4). Why isn't it being removed like the state in blue rectangular (2 2 2 4)? It should be removed as this state has appeared already in `vectorClosed` (code above).

What am I doing wrong? This is not the first iteration of the program, it happens in like 6th or 7th loop.

Also, this is probably causing my program to crash later on.

Comment: `vectorCheck.erase(itCheck)` -- This invalidates `itCheck`. `itCheck++` and all future use of `itCheck` (except assigning a new value to it) invokes undefined behavior. (Note that `erase()` returns a valid vector to the element following the removed element.)

Comment: How else then can I remove it without validating it?

Comment: `itCheck = vectorCheck.erase(itCheck)` but then you need to suppress the `itCheck++` on the next iteration or you'll jump over an element. Typically you see these loops go `for (i = c.begin(); i != c.end(); /* nothing */) { if (should_remove_i) { i = c.remove(i); } else { ++i; } }`. If you have access to C++11 then you could use lambdas along with `std::remove_if` to make this task much easier.

Comment: Use `std::erase_if`, and then do one big `vector::erase` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the problem is that you are continuing to use an iterator to an element you erased. `std::vector::erase(i)` is invalidating the `itCheck` iterator.

We can fix this by taking advantage of C++ algorithms like `std::remove_if`.  It may make the code appear more complex at first glance, but you'll find this style of coding lets you reuse pieces of logic, improving the readability and maintainability of your code.

To start, let's write a functor that does the equality comparison you need.

```
struct states_are_equal :
    public std::binary_function<state const *, state const *, bool>
{
    bool operator()(state const * a, state const * b) const {
        return a->player->x == b->player->x &&
               a->player->y == b->player->y &&
               a->box[0].x == b->box[0].x &&
               a->box[0].y == b->box[0].y;
    }
};
```

Now we need a predicate that will return true if the given item is found within another container. This part admittedly may be a bit hard to follow if you are not familiar with the algorithms library.

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Comparer>
struct is_in_container_func :
    public std::unary_function<
        typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type const &,
        bool
    >
{
    is_in_container_func(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Comparer cmp)
        : it_begin(begin), it_end(end), comparer(cmp) { }

    bool operator()(argument_type i) const {
        return std::find_if(it_begin, it_end, std::bind1st(comparer, i)) != it_end;
    }

private:
    Iterator it_begin;
    Iterator it_end;
    Comparer comparer;
};

// This is just a helper to allow template type deduction; its only purpose is to
// allow us to omit the types for Iterator and Comparer when constructing an
// is_in_container_func object.
template <typename Iterator, typename Comparer>
is_in_container_func<Iterator, Comparer> is_in_container(
    Iterator begin, Iterator end, Comparer cmp)
{
    return is_in_container_func<Iterator, Comparer>(begin, end, cmp);
}
```

Now we can put all of these pieces together with `std::remove_if`:

```
std::vector<state*> vectorOpen;
std::vector<state*> vectorClosed;
std::vector<state*> vectorCheck;

// Make one pass, removing elements if they are found in vectorOpen.
std::vector<state*>::iterator new_end = std::remove_if(
    vectorCheck.begin(), vectorCheck.end(),
    is_in_container(vectorOpen.begin(), vectorOpen.end(), states_are_equal()));

// Make another pass, removing elements if they are found in vectorClosed.
new_end = std::remove_if(
    vectorCheck.begin(), new_end,
    is_in_container(vectorClosed.begin(), vectorClosed.end(), states_are_equal()));

// std::remove_if just swaps elements around so that the elements to be removed are
// all together at the end of the vector, and new_end is an iterator to the first
// one.  So, finally, we just need to remove the range [new_end, end()).
vectorCheck.erase(new_end, vectorCheck.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

The `erase` call invalidates the iterator passed to it. It shifts the elements in the vector one place to their left, and returns an iterator to the element after the removed one. Therefore, you should **not** increment the iterator if the `erase` was executed. Like so:

```
for(itCheck = vectorCheck.begin(); itCheck != vectorCheck.end();) { // no increment
    bool found = false;
    for(itOpen = vectorOpen.begin(); itOpen != vectorOpen.end(); itOpen++) {
        if ((*itCheck)->player->x == (*itOpen)->player->x &&
           (*itCheck)->player->y == (*itOpen)->player->y &&
           (*itCheck)->box[0].x == (*itOpen)->box[0].x &&
           (*itCheck)->box[0].y == (*itOpen)->box[0].y) {
            cout << "erasing as in open " << (*itCheck)->player->x << "   " <<    (*itCheck)->player->y << "   " << (*itCheck)->box[0].x << "   " << (*itCheck)->box[0].y << endl;
            itCheck = vectorCheck.erase(itCheck);
            found = true;
            break; // found element and erased it. back to outer loop
        }
    }

    if (!found) ++itCheck;  // didn't find it, need to increment
}
```

Comment: Actually, `vector::erase` invalidates the erased iterator, too. "[Iterators, pointers and references pointing to *position* (or *first*) and beyond are invalidated](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/)". Only iterators before the erased element(s) are still valid.

Comment: @RaymondChen Did I say something to the contrary? (Genuinely curious)

Comment: In your code, after the `vectorCheck.erase(itCheck);`, you break out of the inner `itOpen` loop and return to the `itCheck` loop, so you are continuing to use the `itCheck` iterator, even though it was invalidated by the `vectorCheck.erase(itCheck)`.

Comment: @RaymondChen I assign `itCheck` the value returned by `erase`.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Missed that. My apologies.